# The use of article 'the'?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Which one is correct and why?

> 'One has rightly said that the beauty is only skin deep'

Or

> 'One has rightly said that beauty is only skin deep'.

Comment: The second. It is referring to _beauty_ as an abstract quality, not _the beauty_ of an individual person.

Comment: Can you edit to describe the situation in which these were used? As it stands neither of them sound natural to me but perhaps if we knew what they are about it might help.

Comment: Idiomatically, we don't use ***one*** in contexts like this, and we wouldn't normally use the Perfect verb form either, so it's ***Someone rightly said** that beauty is only skin deep*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Beauty is only skin deep* is a set expression and is without an article.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beauty-is-only-skin-deep

Also, according to

https://www.englishgrammar.org/omission-articles/

> We do not use articles before uncountable and abstract nouns used in a general sense.

> Wisdom is better than riches.

Comment: Can you please explain the reasoning behind this? Why can't you use 'the' before an uncountable noun?  I knew the rule beforehand,  but if you could explain it a bit more,  it might help.